# JQuery .post() made variable in .each function same value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just confused with this problem. I had problem with variable value which inside `$.post` function is different with the parent function `$(element).each(function`, Here's my code :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".list").each(function() {
    var a = $(this).find("input.input-text").val();
    console.log(a);
    $.post("/Somewhere/path/").done(function(e) {
      console.log(a);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list"><input type="text" class="input-text" value="30000"></div>
<div class="list"><input type="text" class="input-text" value="20000"></div>
<div class="list"><input type="text" class="input-text" value="10000"></div>
```

The value of `a` variable in each function is normally shown, like

`30000
20000
10000`

but the value of `a` variable inside `$.post` function is returning the same value like

`10000
10000
10000`

I found alternative with declare `a` variable inside `$.post` function, but is there any another solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: Doesn't look like I can reproduce this. https://jsfiddle.net/L8Ldw2wk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to either do like this

```js
function callerFunction(a) {
    $.post("/Somewhere/path/").done(function(e) {
      console.log(a);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".list").each(function() {
    var a = $(this).find("input.input-text").val();
    callerFunction(a);
  });
});
```

or you have to make the calls synchronously like this

```
function callerFunction(lists, index) {  
  if(lists.length > index) {
      var a = $(lists[index]).find("input.input-text").val();
      $.post("/Somewhere/path/").done(function(e) {
        console.log(a);
        callerFunction(lists, index+1);
      });
   }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var lists = $(".list");
    callerFunction(lists, 0);
});
```

Comment: this is what I want

Answer (score 1):

The trouble you have experienced is due to the asynchronous nature of the Javascript. $.post call is not working in synchronous manner, so all closures (function you input to `$.post().done()`) will work **after the network request is completed.**

For better understanding, inspect the fiddle below. It generally logs -1000, -1000, -1000 to console BUT it still depends on the response time of the network request.

Then to solve that, you may move your `$.post` call to another function (it creates new scope), or make the call synchronously instead of asynchronously.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".list").each(function(){
var a = $(this).find("input.input-text").val();
 $.get('/echo/js/?js=hello%20world!').done(function(e){
  console.info(a);
 });
 a = -1000;
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list"><input type="text" class="input-text" value="30000"></div>
<div class="list"><input type="text" class="input-text" value="20000"></div>
<div class="list"><input type="text" class="input-text" value="10000"></div>
```

Comment: maybe your description is right, but what I want is the output inside $.post is same like in each function 30000 20000 10000

Comment: I already gave the answer. Said that "Then to solve that, you may move your $.post call to another function (it creates new scope), or make the call synchronously instead of asynchronously.".

Answer (score 0):

your code works for me, I just had to add a 'real' path to the post function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".list").each(function() {
    var a = $(this).find("input.input-text").val();
    console.log(a);
    $.post("/echo/json/").done(function(e) {
      console.log(a);
    });
  });
});
```

maybe it helps : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Micio/f04ufmy0/1/)

output:

```
(index):49 30000
(index):49 20000
(index):49 10000
(index):51 30000
(index):51 20000
(index):51 10000
```